# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userDomain' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring MVC and I am facing a problem which seems to me a common one. My hello.jsp is:

```
 <form:form commandName="userDomain" method="post" action="hello.jsp">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><form:label path="userDomain.emailId">First Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="userDomain.emailId" /></td> 
  </tr>

 </form:form>
```

And controller is :

```
 @Controller
public class HelloWorldController {



 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String hi(@ModelAttribute("userDomain") UserDomain userDomain, BindingResult      result) {


return "hello";
 }

}
```

UserDomain is :

```
 public class UserDomain {

private long userId;
private String name;
private String emailId;
private int numberOfFeedsUsed;
private String password;
private String rePassword;

    setters and getters..

  }
```

The code is simple but the error I am facing is:

*SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ChatBooster] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userDomain' available as request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userDomain' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)*

I have searched in internet but I am just not able to resolve it. Can anyone help me out here?

**Edit 1: Even this one is not working.**

hello.jsp:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="userDomain" method="post" action="hello">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="emailId">First Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Last Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

HelloWorldController:

```
        @Controller
  public class HelloWorldController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String hello() {
   return "hello";
  }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView hi() {
  // String message = "Hi " + name + "!";

  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("hello");
    mav.addObject("userDomain",new UserDomain());
    return mav;
  }

  @ModelAttribute("userDomain")
  public UserDomain getUserDomain(){
  return new UserDomain();
    }

 }
```

web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring Hello World</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>chatbooster</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>chatbooster</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/chatbooster-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   </web-app>
```

chatbooster-servlet.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans x lns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WebContent/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Please check this link,May be it will helpful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34509444/3804255

Answer (score 0):

Controller should look like this.  It could have not been working because the request method was a post.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView  hi() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("hello");
mav.addObject(new UserDomain());
   return mav;
```

}

JSP shoud be what was posted below from @Ralph

```
<form:form commandName="userDomain" method="post" action="hello.jsp">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">First Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
    </tr>
  </table>  <!-- BTW: your closing table tag was missing -->
</form:form>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried that out but the error is same. It seems I am doing a very stupid mistake. I am posting the edited code as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should name `userDomain` not in the `form:input` and `form:label` tag if you have it already in the `form:form` tag. (`form:input path="emailId" />` instead of `form:input path="userDomain.emailId" />`)

```
<form:form commandName="userDomain" method="post" action="hello.jsp">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="emailId">First Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td> 
    </tr>
  </table>  <!-- BTW: your closing table tag was missing -->
</form:form>
```

Try this controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView show() {
          return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp", "userDomain" new UserDomain());
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView create(@Valid UserDomain userDomain, BindingResult bindingResult) {
          if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
              return new ModelAndView("hello", "userDomain" userDomain);
          } else {
              process(userDomain);
              return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("show"));
          }
     }
 }
```

And make sure that your form "invoke" the controller, not the jsp directly. (just remove `.jsp` from the action).

Comment: Combine IT with Manuel's answer.

Comment: I have tried out every suggestion but the error is same. This is my first attempt in Spring MVC so please pardon me for any silly mistake.

Comment: I have even tried out the same example as given in http://candidjava.com/spring-mvc-form-controller-example-prgram-eclipse and I am facing the same error. I don't know why it is happening? I am running FormDetails.jsp of the example by tomcat 6.

Comment: I have added an example controller, but be carefull it is writen without an IDE, so it mayby contains some typos.

Comment: The error is still there. I want to point out one thing is my jsp pages are not in web inf folder but in webcontent folder. It is because tomcat is not able to find out resource when placed in web inf folder. And I am running hello.jsp directly. Is there anything wrong in the approach. I am adding web.xml and related servlet.xml

Comment: @user746458 please add it to your question instead

Comment: I jave added the same in my question. I think may be there is something wrong in web.xml

Comment: Can anyone suggest me anything over here...I am not able to figure out what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you upload The complete project anywhere?

Comment: I have downloaded an example related to my case and is working in my system. I will try to find out the problem using that example and will post the solution in case I find out.